# Encryption in SET protocol

Tags: encryption, public-key, symmetric

I have a rough idea of what is symmetric and asymmetric encryption, but I can't apply the idea to the SET protocol (Secure Electronic Transaction
Specification), so how the symmetric and asymmetric encryption are used in the SET protocol? Also I want to know more about the Preq messages.

Answer (score 1):

> how the symmetric and asymmetric encryption are used in the SET protocol?

As per section 3.2 (which goes into further detail) of the SET specification [here](http://www.maithean.com/docs/set_bk1.pdf):

**Symmetric Encryption**

> SET will rely on cryptography to ensure message confidentiality. In SET, message data will
> be encrypted using a randomly generated symmetric encryption key. This key, in turn, will
> be encrypted using the message recipient’s public key. This is referred to as the “digital
> envelope” of the message and is sent to the recipient along with the encrypted message itself.
> After receiving the digital envelope, the recipient decrypts it using his or her private key to
> obtain the randomly generated symmetric key and then uses the symmetric key to unlock the
> original message.

**Asymmetric Encryption**

> SET uses a distinct public/private key pair to create the digital signature. Thus, each SET
> participant will possess two asymmetric key pairs: a “key exchange” pair, which is used in
> the process of encryption and decryption, and a “signature” pair for the creation and
> verification of digital signatures. Note that the roles of the public and private keys are
> reversed in the digital signature process where the private key is used to encrypt (sign) and
> the public key is used to decrypt (verify the signature).

---

You can find even more detailed information in the Formal Protocol Definition [here](http://www.maithean.com/docs/set_bk3.pdf) which also goes into some detail on PReq messages (on PDF page 84).